Como chamar um método do componente filho no componente pai no angularw
Como consigo chamar um método do componente filho no componente pai no Angular? Tenho um método de editar no componente pai, porém, dentro dele preciso realizar algumas verificação que são possíveis apenas no componente filho.
Eu tentei usando Event e View mas não deu certo, costuma dar undefined.
Método do componente pai:
onEdit() {

    this.formRef.edit()
  }

Este é o método no componente pai e uma tentativa de chamar o método do componente filho.
  @ViewChild(FilhoComponente) formRef: FilhoComponente;


Para compartilhar informações entre componentes pai<->filho pode-se utilizar os decorators @Input() e Output(). Leia mais a respeito na doc oficial https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs, aqui também tem um artigo de como funciona https://maffonso.medium.com/angular-8-intera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-componentes-cf19b46e624e

Para chamar um método de um componente filho em um componente pai no Angular, você pode usar a diretiva @ViewChild. Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer isso:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/adoSP.png
No componente filho, defina um método que deseja chamar no componente pai:
No componente pai, use ViewChild para acessar o componente filho e chamar o método desejado:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/rdefp.png
Desta forma, quando o botão no componente pai é clicado, o método metodoDoFilho() do componente filho será chamado. Certifique-se de importar o componente filho (FilhoComponent) no componente pai (PaiComponent) e também de declarar o componente filho no template do componente pai.
